# How can I improve this UV-Mapping?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm very noob in Blender as a result I'm struggling to unwrap a M24 grenade 3D-Mesh properly.

My first attempt to improve the UV-Mapping was making the irregular polygons as squares or rectangles using a Python plugin so that I could apply textures easily on Gimp. The result is this one:

[image]

Despite doing this I'm still not happy with the changes as the trial texture's squares are not well distributed. As you can see in the photos those parts divided by the seams have like a "cut" in the texture and I don't know if that will affect the texture added with Gimp.

[image]

Could you provide me with some tips to improve my UV-Mapping?

Thank you very much for your help.
Héctor

Comment: There are some tricks to get rid of seams provided witth UV mapping - there's no way to unwrap without seams. However the texture is stretched quite heavily along Y axis (if talking about axes from UV map) that results in the image stretching starting from the horizontal seam and all the way down. This is probably what you should pay attention at.

Comment: Whenever possible, you should place your seams in regions that are not so noticeable. Near the top of your screen shot there is an extra seam that loops around and doesn't appear to have any purpose. I would get rid of that. Usually you can get good rectangular unwraps using "Follow Active Quads", but I'm curious, what Python plugin did you use?

Comment: The plugin I am using is the following one. It automatices the process of making rectangles in the UV islands.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Uv_Squares

I could improve quite much the UV-Mapping clearing those unnecessary seams you told me. Now the squares over the grenade have the same size and the "cuts" have also disappeared.

Comment: There's one last thing I would like to change and improve: the top of the grenade.

[!link](http://tineye.com/search/03b409f37b045359e65f83224d744b9644c2c1c5/)

How can I eliminate the "cuts" in the texture without clearing the seam?

Comment: Besides all that been said, consider using seamless textures, you can adjust a texture to be seamless in Gimp or Photoshop or any other photo processing software

Answer (score 1):

to change the size of these squares, you should scale uv-islands. this time it is y-scale. after you are happy with squares, you can scale island on x and y simultaneously to occupy most of available texture space. the biggest island should be the island that will show lot's of texture details. and you can also rotate the islands by 90 degrees.